# Equality of Trig sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ I'd like to prove $$\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}-\lbrace0\rbrace }\bigg(\frac{\cos(2\pi \alpha n)+i\sin(2\pi \alpha n)}{n}\bigg)=\sum _{n\ge 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi n\alpha)}{n}$$

However, the only way I see this happening is if both $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}-\lbrace 0 \rbrace}\frac{\sin(2\pi\alpha n)}{n}=2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi \alpha n)}{n}$$ *and* $$\sum _{n\in \mathbb{Z}-\lbrace 0 \rbrace}\frac{\cos(2\pi \alpha n)}{n}=0$$

I have no clue on how to get started with the latter equations, if they are even true. Can I get some guidance here, please.

Answer (score 1):

The two equations are true formally, at least, since $\sin(2\pi an)$ is an *odd* function and $\cos(2\pi an)$ is an *even* function of $n$:  The sum on the left-hand side runs over *all* nonzero integers, so if you reorder the sum (formally) pairing up $+n$ and $-n$ terms, the sine terms double and the cosines cancel.

Comment: since sine is odd, wouldn't all of the sine terms cancel out?

Comment: @cap, no, it's the cosine terms that cancel, because of the $n$ in the denominator.  That is, $\sin(2\pi an)/n$ is an even function, and $\cos(2\pi an)/n$ is an odd function of $n$.